# SoapUI disable logs for a TestCase

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to disable logs in soapui while running a test case.
So that no logs gets generated.

I have checked SoapUI preferences and found and option to disable groovy logs, but it does suppress logs only for groovy scripts.

How can i suppress logs altogether.

Answer (score 0):

SOAPUI uses `log4j`, and there is a configuration file in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui-log4j.xml`. You can edit this file and set the `<level>` to:

```
<level value="OFF" />
```

For the `<logger>`'s that you want to disable.

Remember to restart SOAPUI after changes in the `log4j.xml` config file in order to load this changes.

Hope it helps,

Comment: If you need to suppress logging for SoapUITestCaseRunner check this thread https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/SoapUI-overwrites-and-closes-log4j-settings/m-p/30694#M15048.